# React-Router - Redirect if URL parameter not passed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I want the redirect back to home if the params are not passed with the url.
How can I achieve this?
I tried something like this, but it`s not working:

```
export default function Summary() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  if (!id) {
    navigate("/home");
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved in in the router itself:

```
        <Route
          path={`${LocalRoutes.summary}/:id`}
          element={<Summary/>}
        />
        <Route path={LocalRoutes.summary} element={<Navigate to="/home" />} />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Redirect} from "react-router-dom"

if(!id){
return <Redirect to="/" />
}
```